# display border on hover using tweenMax

Tags: javascript, gsap

I am trying to add a colored border when I hover on the html element  through JS, I'm chooses to use TweenMax library and i'm  new to it so I don't really understand what am I doing wrong this is my, I'm trying to tweek the code  since this morning with little success this is my function:

```
self.$('p').hover(function() {
       console.log('ok');
       var $t = $(this);
       var $a = $(this).find('a');
       $(this).lvBtnUnderline('over');
       TweenMax.to($p, .5, {
       color: '#FF0000'
    });
    TweenMax.to($t, .5, {
       borderLeftColor: '#FF0000',
       opacity: .5
    });
    }, function() {
      var $t = $(this);
       var $a = $(this).find('a');
      $(this).lvBtnUnderline('out');
      TweenMax.to($p, .5, {
        color: '#FFFFFF'
      });
TweenMax.to($t, .5, {
    borderLeftColor: '#FFFFFF',
    opacity: 0
});
});

    this is my html element     
       <p>
        <a class="certificato" 

         href="../sites/all/themes/lazzeri/assets/ifs_certificato.pdf" 
         target="_blank">
         <div>Scarica Certificato IFS</div>
         <div class="underline"></div>
        </a>
        </p>
```

It should display a red border and some other animations based on .the lvBtnUnderline function I'm calling above but nothing seems to work,
can someone explain me where is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your HTML is invalid. You can't have a div inside of a p tag.

Second, there is no variable `$p` (at least in the code that you shared). Fixing those issues, it works:

https://codepen.io/GreenSock/pen/MWYeaXq?editors=0010

Comment: Thank you for your help it definetely cleared up my ideas, I should have specified that the code I posted is part of a bigger project so there is a reason the html is structured in that way.

Comment: It doesn't matter if it's part of a larger project or not - invalid is invalid. Also, if this answers your question you should click the check mark next to the answer that satisfies your question :)